# Reading memory addresses of other windows applications

Tags: delphi, debugging, memory, editor

I am trying to build an application that retrieves data from memory used by another application.  The idea is very simple to a game cheat editor that identifies processes running in windows and allowing the user to view all the data that process has in memory.

Are there any tutorials on methods for accessing this or perhaps a component that simplifies the access to memory?

Comment: What Windows version(s)?

Comment: I'm working on Xp but looking for a generic solution

Comment: How does that matter to this question, @Jan?

Comment: @Rob IIRC things like ReadProcesMemory have become more difficult (tighter security) in later versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `OpenProcess` or `CreateProcess` to get a handle to the process you're interested in, and then use `ReadProcessMemory`. Remember to pay close attention to whether an address is in your own program's address space or that of the foreign process.

Comment: And be sure you have enough rights to perform `ReadProcessMemory` (: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880 are the values to pass in `OpenProcess`. If you do not have enough rights, you get an `Access Denied` error.